# .Net serializer is serializing DateTime in different precisions

Tags: json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

**My Code:** I have an API currently, once I get a request from the client, we save the information along with the time of the request which is DateTime.UtcNow()(this is not received from the client, we do it in my code). and save it in the couchbase.

**Problem:**
Sometimes the DateTime field is saved with different precisions, ideally I would like to save this field with a precision upto 7 decimal points(e.g:**2020-12-28T18:45:24.6901637Z**) but sometimes .net is saving this time with different precisions(**2020-12-28T18:49:10.02396Z**).

Can someone please help me figure out why is this happening randomly. I am using .net core 3.1.

Code Sample:

```
var obj = new obj{empId = 111, empType = 'Contractor', status = 'Ontime', lastUpdatedTime = DateTime.UtcNow}; var id = 111;

var response = await _bucket.InsertAsync<dynamic>(id, obj);

response in couchbase: { empId : 111, empType : Contractor, status : 'OnTime', lastUpdatedTime : '2020-12-28T18:45:24.6901637Z', }, { empId : 222, empType : Contractor, status : 'Delayed', lastUpdatedTime : '2020-12-28T18:50:19.12345Z', }
```

I apologize for any kind of vague information i provided. please let me know if i need to put any other information which will make more sense

Comment: If you are using [tag:system.text.json], it looks like this is intentional.  In [`JsonWriterHelper.TrimDateTimeOffset(Span<byte> buffer, out int bytesWritten)`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/2ef14c3ff6319d838211f9c30832c003744c8f09/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Writer/JsonWriterHelper.Date.cs#L43) there is explicit code to `// Remove trailing zeros`.  Can you [edit] your question to show how you serialize to JSON?  A [mcve] would be ideal, and maximize the chance we can help you.

Comment: added a code sample, please let me know if that helps

Comment: I am using newtonsoft

Comment: If you are using newtonsoft might you please [edit] your question to share how you are calling it?  What is `_bucket`?  Is that what is making the call to newtonsoft?  Also, is `obj` some c# data model you designed?

Comment: @dbc bucket is nothing but a couchbase bucket(no sql data base which we are using to store the information) so the .net couchbase sdk we install will directly serialize the object model which i provide and insert it into the couchbase