# .NET Core 3.1 Web API does not round trip DateTime properly

Tags: json, .net-core, serialization

I have a class with `DateTime` properties. One endpoint returns this class, the other takes it as a `[FromBody]` parameter.

Returning an object of this class from a web API endpoint serialises it to JSON with seven decimal places. Here's the code.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Models.SiteData
{
    public class SiteDataRequest
    {
        public SiteDataRequest()
        {
            Responses = new List<SiteData>();
            Metadata = new Metadata();
        }

        public Metadata Metadata { get; set; }
        public List<SiteData> Responses { get; set; }



        private static Random rnd = new Random();
        public void GenerateData(int responseCount, int stationCount, int inversionTowersCount, int equipmentStatusCount)
        {

            var statistics = new Statistics()
            {
                StatusRecords = equipmentStatusCount,
                ExecutionTime = 10,
                ReadingPeriods = responseCount,
                StationRecords = stationCount,
                TowersRecords = inversionTowersCount
            };

            Metadata = new Metadata
            {
                RequestDate = DateTime.Now,
                RequestSite = "TEST_SITE",
                RequirePeriodStart = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-30),
                RequirePeriodEnd = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),
                Statistics = statistics,
                TransactionID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };

            var startTime = DateTime.Now;

            var responseToGenerator = responseCount; 
            for (var responseIndex = 0; responseIndex < responseToGenerator; responseIndex++)
            {

                var response = new SiteData
                {
                    Timestamp = startTime,
                };
                Responses.Add(response);

                var stationsToGenerate = stationCount;
                for (var stationIndex = 0; stationIndex < stationsToGenerate; stationIndex++)
                {
                    var station = new Station
                    {
                        id = $"station_{stationIndex}"
                    };
                    GenerateData(station, Station.Names, 0f, 5000f);
                    response.Stations.Add(station);
                }
                for (var inversionTowerIndex = 0; inversionTowerIndex < inversionTowersCount; inversionTowerIndex++)
                {
                    var tower = new InversionTower
                    {
                        id = $"invtower_{inversionTowerIndex}"
                    };
                    GenerateData(tower, InversionTower.Names, 0f, 5000f);
                    response.InversionTowers.Add(tower);
                }
                for (var equipmentStatusIndex = 0; equipmentStatusIndex < equipmentStatusCount; equipmentStatusIndex++)
                {
                    var equipmentStatus = new EquipmentStatus
                    {
                        id = $"equipstatus_{equipmentStatusIndex}"
                    };
                    GenerateData(equipmentStatus, EquipmentStatus.Names, 0f, 5000f);
                    response.EquipmentStatus.Add(equipmentStatus);
                }

                startTime = startTime.AddSeconds(1);
            }
        }

        private static readonly Random r = new Random();
        internal void GenerateData(ValueRange objectToSet, float minimum, float maximum)
        {
            var minValue = 0;
            var maxValue = (int)rnd.Next(minValue, (int)maximum * 1000);
            var value = r.Next(minValue, maxValue);

            objectToSet.Low = minValue / 1000f;
            objectToSet.High = maxValue / 1000f;

            objectToSet.Value = value / 1000f;
        }
        internal void GenerateData(SensorValue sensorValue, float minimum, float maximum)
        {
            var minValue = (int)minimum * 1000;
            var maxValue = (int)maximum * 1000;
            var value = r.Next(minValue, maxValue);
            sensorValue.Value = value / 1000f;
        }

        internal void GenerateData(Station objectToSet, List<string> names, float minimum, float maximum)
        {
            foreach (var n in names)
            {
                var esv = new SensorValue { Name = n };
                GenerateData(esv, minimum, maximum);
                objectToSet.SensorValues.Add(esv);
            }
        }

        internal void GenerateData(InversionTower objectToSet, List<string> names, float minimum, float maximum)
        {
            foreach (var n in names)
            {
                var esv = new SensorValue { Name = n };
                GenerateData(esv, minimum, maximum);
                objectToSet.SensorValues.Add(esv);
            }
        }

        internal void GenerateData(EquipmentStatus objectToSet, List<string> names, float min, float max)
        {
            foreach (var n in names)
            {
                var value = new ValueRange();
                GenerateData(value, min, max);

                var esv = new EquipmentStatusValue { Name = n, Reading = value };
                objectToSet.Readings.Add(esv);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Npgsql;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Controllers
{
    [Route("api/sitedata")]
    [ApiController]
    public class SiteDataApiController : BaseController
    {
        private readonly ILogger logger;
        private readonly IUserService _userService;
        private readonly ISiteVerifier _siteVerifier;
        private readonly ISiteDataPackageRepository _repoSiteDataPackage;
        private readonly SiteDataService _siteDataService;

        public SiteDataApiController(ILogger<SiteDataApiController> logger, ISiteDataPackageRepository repoSiteDataPackage, IUserService userService, ISiteVerifier siteVerifier, SiteDataService siteDataService)
        {
            _siteVerifier = siteVerifier;
            _siteDataService = siteDataService;
            _repoSiteDataPackage = repoSiteDataPackage;
            this.logger = logger;
            _userService = userService;
        }

        [Authorize,HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ReceiveData([FromBody] SiteDataRequest siteDataRequest)
        {
            var requestUserId = _userService.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);
            var siteDataResponse = _siteDataService.VerifyData(siteDataRequest);


            if (siteDataResponse.Success)
            {
                logger.LogInformation("SiteData is processed for {site} on {date}", siteDataRequest.Metadata.RequestSite, siteDataRequest.Metadata.RequestDate);
                try
                {
                    var insertResult = await _repoSiteDataPackage.InsertAsync(siteDataRequest);
                    return Ok(insertResult);
                }
                catch (NpgsqlException ex)
                {
                    return TranslateExceptionToResult(ex);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                logger.LogWarning("SiteData is invalid {messages}", siteDataResponse.Messages);
                return BadRequest(siteDataResponse);
            }


        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Do not deliver this in the final project, this is to generate sample data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [Authorize,HttpPost("sample")]
        public SiteDataRequest GenerateSampleData()
        {
            var sd = new SiteDataRequest();
            sd.GenerateData(5, 10, 5, 4);
            return sd;
        }

    }
}
```

Here's the start of the JSON you get from invoking the `/sample` endpoint.

```json
{
  "metadata": {
    "transactionID": "1cac2cff-d28b-457b-8dff-dab05fa751a5",
    "requestDate": "2022-02-16T18:03:36.7186639+10:00",
    "requestSite": "TEST_SITE",
    "requirePeriodStart": "2022-02-16T17:33:36.7187564+10:00",
    "requirePeriodEnd": "2022-02-16T18:33:36.7188009+10:00",
```

Giving this to the `ReceiveData` endpoint triggers a 400 error.

When I capture the JSON and trim the date strings to three or fewer decimal places, suddenly the JSON can be parsed.

**What governs this implicit serialisation?** If it's config driven, why is in and out different given that the two endpoints are in the same controller?

This [.Net serializer is serializing DateTime in different precisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583831) seems like it may be related. The comments, if not the question.

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lsI5Hg) in .NET (Core) 6. Perhaps this was a bug that was fixed since. As .NET Core 3.1 reaches End-Of-Life on May 2022, and .NET 6 is the new Long-Term-Support version, you should upgrade to .NET 6 anyway

Comment: BTW `GenerateSampleData` shouldn't be async, as it doesn't do anything asynchronously.  `await Task.FromResult(sd)` actually returns `sd` immediatelly. If you want to implement an async base method, or generate a result in a faked async method, you should use `return Task.FromResult(Ok(sd));`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos ISO8601 and the structure of my class are orthogonal to the question of why the implicit serialisation and deserialisation done by the framework are asymmetric. I've been pushing the idea that we should migrate to 6 for the last six months. I didn't realise 3.1 expired in May. That's our delivery date. If you can suggest a search topic for how to configure the implicit (de)serialisation in 3.1 I would be grateful.

Comment: What does `SiteDataRequest` look like? What is the type of the date properties? A `DateTime` can only represent UTC or "local" time while your JSON contains an offset. `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<DateTime>("\"2022-02-16T17:33:36.7187564+10:00\"")` will produce a UTC value, `2022-02-16T07:33:36.7187564+00:00`

Comment: ISO8601 is central to the question. You're producing values that aren't valid. The LTS expiration schedule is known years in advance, not something announced just now. Are you going to release something that will be obsolete before it's even deployed?

Comment: As for how to overcome this in .NET Core 3.1 - first try to produce meaningful values, ie no nanoseconds. This will cause other problems as well, eg equality or search problems. Second, you can change how specific types are serialized with a [custom JsonConverter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-core-3-1). The doc example actually shows how to customize DateTimeOffset serialization.

Comment: I know how to control an explicit serialisation. I don't know how to control the implicit serialisation that occurs when a web api method returns an object. How to do this is the entirety of my question.

Comment: Use a custom JsonConverter and register it with the serializer or in Startup.cs, with `AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(...)` or `AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(...)`

Comment: That's an answer. If you present it as such I will accept it.

Comment: If the bug was how `DateTime.Parse` behaved, you'll still have to trim nanoseconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To control the implicit serialisation done by the framework, use a custom `JsonConverter`.

Register it with the serializer or in `Startup.cs`, with `AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(...)` or `AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(...)`

The date problem appears to be with the default serialisation of dates.

```cs
using System;

namespace _deser
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var d = DateTime.Now;
            Console.WriteLine($"Default: {d.ToString("o")}");
            d = d.ToUniversalTime();
            Console.WriteLine($"Default UTC: {d.ToString("o")}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Custom UTC: {d.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ")}");
        }
    }
}
```

Using UTC lets you use a literal `Z`. It's simpler.

produces

```
Default serialisation: 2022-02-17T08:40:13.0051941+10:00
Default serialisation of UTC: 2022-02-16T22:40:13.0133860Z
Custom serialisation of UTC: 2022-02-16T22:40:13.013Z
```

When I set out to apply the fix, I discovered someone already did this, but only defined a picture string for three decimal places (and failed to control the number of places produced when serialising).

I imagine this precision was chosen because JavaScript uses Unix time which is an integer count of milliseconds from the 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z epoch.

The problem is that when you add explicit picture strings you have to use ParseExact, and that then means you have to define *all* the picture strings. I couldn't see a way to handle an arbitrary number of places, so I supplied eight picture strings for 0 to 7 places.